# How to write an array with three indices in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have a series of equal cubes in 3D space with known centers. Given a cube center, I can give rest of information about that cube. In fact, each center's coordinates in 3D represents sort of an ID for the corresponding cube.

In my program in JavaScripts, each cube is an object. It has properties such as center, color, vertices, etc. I can have an array such as "allcubes" that can store all cubes in one place and then recall them by "allcubes[0]", "allcubes[1]",... . However, I want to write my program in a way that when I give the center coordinates it immediately could say that which cube I'm pointing at.

Of course, I can make a for loop and use comparison to find it out but it is not efficient when the number of cubes are high. I am looking for something like an array which accepts three arguments, for example if we write "allcubes[i,j,k]" it can say which cube we are pointing at or we may use dynamic object naming and assign each cube with a name based on their center coordinates but I really don't know how to do this.

I would really appreciate that if you could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Make an array, where each element is an array, and each element of those elements is an array. Then you can write `allcubes[i][j][k]`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example? Cause I saw couple of examples on websites but I couldn't really figure that out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. Instead, you make arrays of arrays for 2 dimensions, arrays of arrays of arrays for 3 dimensions, and so on. To access successive dimensions, you simply index the return value of the previous access. To access an element of a 3-dimensional array, it's `arrayName[i][j][k]`.

Here's how you would loop over the entire array, processing every cube.

```
for (var i = 0; i < allCubes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < allCubes[i].length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < allCubes[i][j].length; k++) {
            var thisCube = allCubes[i][j][k];
            // do something with thisCube
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with multi-dimensional arrays, be sure to make sure you check whether each dimension exists (unless you know that each dimension exists)

```
var cubes = [];

function GetCube(i,j,k){
 if(!cubes[i] instanceof Array)return null;
 if(!cubes[i][j] instanceof Array)return null;
 return cubes[i][j][k];
}

function SetCube(i,j,k,value){
 if(!cubes[i] instanceof Array)cubes[i] = [];
 if(!cubes[i][j] instanceof Array)cubes[i][j] = [];
 cubes[i][j][k] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your above helpful ideas, I wrote this and it works fine. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you all!

```
   a = new Array( 5 );
   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
      a[ i ] = new Array( 5 );
      for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ ){
        a[ i ][ j ] = new Array( 5 );
      }
   }
```